# Add image next to a horizontal flat list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am quite new to React Native and am trying to create a screen where there are 2x rows of images scrolling horizontally across (which I've done with a FlatList as in screenshot) but I want to have one larger image to the left of these images. However, whenever I add an image to my code, it shows above, rather than next to. Here's my code attempt and screenshot of what I've got so far:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    marginHorizontal: 16 * v,
    marginVertical: 16 * v,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  smileImage: {
    width: 240 * v,
    height: 240 * v,
  },
})

const HomeView = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView horizontal>
          <Image source={Images.smile} style={styles.smileImage} />
          <FlatList
            data={[
              '1',
              '2',
              '3',
              '4',
              '5',
              '6',
            ]}
            numColumns={2}
            renderItem={() => (
              <View
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  height: 150,
                  width: 150,
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderColor: 'black',
                  margin: 20,
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  )
}
```

Can someone please help me to get a bigger image appearing next to the FlatList on the left hand side ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prop of **Flatlist** named `listHeaderComponent` and you can add  image in it

```
<Flatlist listHeaderComponent={<Image source={{uri:link of image}}/>}/>
```